# Make the parentheses in function calls optional

Tags: javascript, function, object

Hey, I am about to rewrite the core file for my JavaScript library and I am looking for better ways of doing everything. One of these is how I make parentheses optional, for example some function calls look like this.

```
Spark('p').content('Hello, World');
```

And others like this.

```
Spark.browser();
```

So I have optional parentheses for the Spark function. Am I right in saying this would be the best way?

```
window.Spark = function(arg1, arg2) {
    return {
        fn: function() {
            alert('run');
        }
    };
};

for(var f in Spark())
    Spark[f] = Spark()[f];

Spark.fn();
Spark(true, false).fn();
```

It just seems wrong to me although it is the only method I have come up with that works.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh sorry, as my examples show, I need to use the `Spark` function with or without brackets, I have already accomplished this via the method above but is there a better, cleaner way.

Comment: Yes, but stepping back, what's the actual requirement? Why is `Spark` a function if it doesn't matter whether you call it? If you can ignore the fact it has arguments? Your solution doesn't make the brackets optional, it just mixes in the properties of the object resulting from a call to `Spark` with no arguments into the `Spark` function object. I'm having trouble finding a reasonable use-case for that, as opposed to having a default `Spark` object (perhaps `DefSpark` or even `Spark.default`).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure. Why do you want to make the parentheses optional? If it's so you can run the `Spark.browser` function with out appending braces, then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: No, it was that `Spark` required parenthesis that I wanted to make optional, not its functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path, but be careful. As it stands, the `fn` function will be instantiated every time you call `Spark(...)`, which will cause minor performance and memory usage issues.

A cleaner approach would be to use a class and store all those functions in the prototype to avoid unnecessary memory usage:

```
window.Spark = (function(){

  function inner(arg1, arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
  }

  inner.prototype = {
    fn : function() { alert('run') }
  };

  function S(arg1, arg2) { return new inner(arg1, arg2) }

  var dflt = S();
  for (var f in dflt) S[f] = dflt[f];

  return S;
})();
```

Comment: *"... which will cause minor performance and memory usage issues..."* Not necessarily minor. It depends how many of these things there are going to be.

Comment: I am still experimenting with this code to see if I can access everything I want, it looks like it has done the job, I will accept if it has.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: you're right, of course. Performance degradation always depends on how often the suboptimal code runs and the size of the data on which it runs. ;-)

Comment: And just to clarify I just did some basic tests and it took < 1ms to initialise. So I don't see where you think these performance issues are coming from. This test is using the method that may cause "minor performance and memory usage issues" http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/qDXC5/